# How to highlight last div with specific css-class , if the number of div with specific class is unknown?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to highlight last div with class="block" in the following html-structure, if the number of div with class="block" is unknown? (With help of css-selectors)

HTML:

```
<div class="main"> 
   <div class="block">
      1
   </div>

   <div class="block">
      2
   </div>

   <div class="block">
      3
   </div>

   <div>
      4
   </div>

   <div>
      5
   </div>

</div>

<div>
  6
</div>

<div>
  7
</div>
```

There, for example, I want highlight third div.

Comment: Why can't you just include this code in your original question since you edited the codepen that you linked there?

Comment: there's no last-of-class selector - so I don't think you can do this

Comment: Unfortunately as of now, CSS cannot make out which is the last element in the DOM with a specific `class`.. The best you can do here is either you can call multiple classes, say `block last` and than use `.last` to target or your last element, but as you said that number of `.block` is unknown, than you might have to use jQuery to target the element.

Comment: For BoltClock's a Unicorn: Because old question already has answers and it is not rightly - update old question, imho.

Comment: Learning about pseudo classes will help you immensely. CSS-Tricks is superb - http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/.